# searching mysql database with urlencode

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to ask this question before I start coding because I know it's going to give me problems. Lets say I have the following URL:

www.mysite.com/script.php?id=12345&email=email%40email.com

now let's say I want to search a database using the $_GET variables. My question is, will the % sign in the $_GET['email'] variable cause issues with a MySQL query in PHP, since the % sign means something else in MySQL? Or Can I just go ahead and search the database with that input and not have any issues?

Comment: You could always just use `urldecode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
www.mysite.com/script.php?id=12345&email=email%40email.com
```

Will give you the following value in $_GET: email@email.com (so, already decoded)

Of course you should use a function like mysql_real_escape_string before using this value in any query, but using url decode or something is not necessary.

mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement
http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string